# Javascript : Change selection background

Tags: javascript, css, selection

How should I do this in `Javascript`?

```
// CSS
*::-moz-selection{
 background:transparent; 
}
```

I tried these but doesn't really works:

```
// Javascript
document.mozSelection = "transparent";
document.body.mozSelection = "transparent";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a rule to the stylesheet.

```
// Get the first stylesheet 
var ssheet = document.styleSheets[0];

if ("insertRule" in ss) {
    ss.insertRule('#yourdivcontainer::-moz-selection { background: transparent; }', 0);        
}
```

IMO, it's not a good practice anyway. You should create a CSS class with the selection color and change the class itself via JS instead of the style.

Answer (score 2):

`::` selectors are for pseudo-elements, CSS objects that don't correspond to actual element nodes. Because there is no element node to match `::-moz-selection`, you can't style it directly on an element's `.style.background` property.

Instead you would have to insert a new stylesheet rule duplicating the above CSS (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript) for a couple of methods of doing that).