# Dynamically adding @font-face rule in IE 8 and less

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

I'm adding @font-face rules using IEs stylesheet.addRule() method. However, the @ symbol is a disallowed character for the 'selector' argument of that method so I'm getting a 'invalid argument' error.

```
s.addrule("@font-face", "font-family: 'Font Name'; src:url('/fonts/font.eot') etc...)";
```

Is there some other way to dynamically add these rules?

I've tried setting the innerHTML property of the style element, setting the cssText property of the styleSheet property, and appending a text node to the style element as well (which crashes IE).

Any other methods to try?

Comment: Why no conditional comments? Further more your style-string is quoted wrong. And from tbe spec on msdn, isn't the signature ...(selector, style [, index]) ?

Comment: How do conditional comments help? Yeah, the function signature is as you state - have I done something wrong? It works fine in Webkit incidentally.

Comment: [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) provide a way to specify CSS to apply only to IE or specific versions thereof. Example: `<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">@font-face { font-family: 'Font Name'; src: url('/fonts/font.eot'); }</style><![endif]-->`

Comment: `@font-face` isn't a valid selector. Take a look at the description of the parameters on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358796(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, I know what conditional comments *are*. I'm asking how do they help insert @font-face rules dynamically with JavaScript? Unless I'm missing something, they don't.

Comment: Yes, I know @font-face isn't a valid selector. That's what I said in the question. I've either worded the question very badly, or people are commenting without reading it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the cssText property does work, but you MUST insert the style element into the document before adding the @font-face rule to the document. Eg...

```
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.type = "text/css";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
s.styleSheet.cssText = "@font-face {" + rule + "}";
```

As far as I can tell it is perfectly possible to set other types of CSS rules before inserting the style element into the page, but not @font-face.

Eg... this works fine:

```
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.type = "text/css";
s.styleSheet.cssText = "body { background: red}";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

But this crashes IE 8 and less:

```
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.type = "text/css";
s.styleSheet.cssText = "@font-face {" + rule + "}";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Chrome tells me 'styleSheet' is undefined. 'cssText' seems to be a property of `s.style` however. With that said, it doesn't insert anything into the `<style>` tag =/