# Changing all body elements' color to target value 

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to change all body elements' color with a single click in javascript. like;

```
a.url{
color:#000;
}
div.sample{
color:#000;
}
table td.sample{
color:#000;
}
```

### can i change all color properties of elements to #CCCCCC for example?

I think i have to clear my question. I don't want to change all elements color to target value, i want to change lets say; all blue colors to black. just blue colors, not all of them.

Comment: *All* elements on the page, or just those elements you've identified in your question?

Comment: all elements with same color properties.

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

html:

```
<button id="changeColor">Change Color</button>
```

and javascript:

```
$('#changeColor').on('click', function(){
    $('*').css('color', '#CCCCCC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$element.click(function() {
  $('body *').css('color', '#ccc !important');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for how to add a stylesheet rule: [How do you add CSS with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript)

Add the rule

```
* {
  color: #CCC !important;
}
```

or possibly:

```
body * {
  color: #CCC !important;
}
```