# CSS in Javascript Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to insert css into a javascript bookmarklet?

something as simple as `#div-name{ display: none !important; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from: [How do you add CSS with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript)

I don't like referring to links as sometimes you'll click through 5 link only to end up at a dead link with a comment look here:

To add style to the page you can:

```
var sheet =document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(sheet);
```

Here is the solution from that page:

You can also do this using DOM Level 2 CSS interfaces:

```
sheet.insertRule('strong { color: red; }', sheet.cssRules.length);
```

...on all but (naturally) IE, which uses its own marginally-different wording:

```
sheet.addRule('strong', 'color: red;', -1);
```

There is a theoretical advantage in this compared to the createElement-set-innerHTML method, in that you don't have to worry about putting special HTML characters in the innerHTML, but in practice style elements are CDATA in legacy HTML, and ‘<’ and ‘&’ are rarely used in stylesheets anyway.

You do need a stylesheet in place before you can started appending to it like this. That can be any existing active stylesheet: external, embedded or empty, it doesn't matter. If there isn't one, the only standard way to create it at the moment is with createElement.