# Add/Remove CSS class attributes to respect to the class not based on Div id

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS elements defined as below:

```
.myRedClass
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

And it is assigned to many Divs( that are having similar appearance). At some point i need to assign some left-margin also. What i am currently doing is; I will add and remove a Predefined Class `.redClass-margin{margin-left:10px}` to each of the required div. The code for this is:

```
$( "myDiv1" ).addClass( "redClass-margin" );
$( "myDiv2" ).addClass( "redClass-margin" );
$( "myDiv3" ).addClass( "redClass-margin" );
```

and so on... Instead for this Can i do changes in the existing css class. Is their any possibility to change the  `.myRedClass` like the following :

```
.myRedClass
    {
      background-color:red;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
```

Either Through script or through `c#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit an existing css stylesheet.

There's a different approach though. If you just want to find all divs that have class `myRedClass`, and add `redClass-margin`, you can find them all with jquery and add class.

```
$('.myRedClass').addClass('redClass-margin');
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get why you want to do this I would just create a new classand append the class name to each element like Eric mentioned.

However there is a [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/inject-new-css-rules/) that tell you how to do what your asking.

Alternatively you could inject rules into your style sheet, again a weird way to do it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript).