# How to write value of one div into another div

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML and I want to pull the value from one div into another and if possible to put a `:` between them.

It is about to add the value of `div class="ITSv"` to the value of `div class="ITSn"`

Source HTML:

```
<div id="HTML_SPEC"
 class="ITSs">
<div class="ITSg">Specifications</div>
<div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">Battery form</div> 
    <div class="ITSv">Cylinder</div>
</div>
<div class="ITSg">Batterie</div>
<div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">battery voltage</div> 
    <div class="ITSv">1,5 V</div>
</div>
<div class="ITSr1">
    <div class="ITSn">Capacity</div> 
    <div class="ITSv">7800 mAh</div>
</div>
```

Target format:

```
<div id="HTML_SPEC"
 class="ITSs">
<div class="ITSg">Specifications</div>
<div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">Batteryform: Cylinder</div> 
</div>
<div class="ITSg">Batterie</div>
<div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">battery voltage: 1,5 V</div> 
</div>
<div class="ITSr1">
    <div class="ITSn">Capacity: 7800 mAh</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following

> 

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('ITSn')).forEach(element => {
element.innerText += ': ' + element.nextElementSibling.innerText;
   element.nextElementSibling.remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="HTML_SPEC"
 class="ITSs">
<div class="ITSg">Specifications</div>
<div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">Battery form</div> 
    <div class="ITSv">Cylinder</div>
</div>
<div class="ITSg">Batterie</div>
<div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">battery voltage</div> 
    <div class="ITSv">1,5 V</div>
</div>
<div class="ITSr1">
    <div class="ITSn">Capacity</div> 
    <div class="ITSv">7800 mAh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

**Don't need Js**. Just try with the css `display` property `after` pseudo-element

```css
.ITSn:after {
  content: ': '
}

.ITSn,
.ITSv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="HTML_SPEC" class="ITSs">
  <div class="ITSg">Specifications</div>
  <div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">Battery form</div>
    <div class="ITSv">Cylinder</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ITSg">Batterie</div>
  <div class="ITSr0">
    <div class="ITSn">battery voltage</div>
    <div class="ITSv">1,5 V</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ITSr1">
    <div class="ITSn">Capacity</div>
    <div class="ITSv">7800 mAh</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in the application where I have this code, Im just able to add an additinoal js code.

Comment: You can do that in multiple ways. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript)