# Add a class to a div after day of month has passed (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I would like to have 31 divs. One for every day of a month.
But I want divs for previous days to look different from future days.
I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this.

**EDIT: I can see how unclear my question was. I am looking for javascript to act on divs that have been created separately. Not for the javascript to create the divs.**

One thought was to have -

```
<div id="day-1" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-2" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-3" class="something">content</div>
```

then, some form of loop checking if the day- id is < d.getDate()
and if so document.getElementById("").className = " pastdate";

then .pastdate can let me change the appearance.

I just want to check if I'm on the right track or if there's an easier way?

Comment: and if the month doesn't have 31 days?

Comment: @ericmp This is only something for the occasional special event, so could be manually changed dependent on the month. Having it adapt automatically to the month would, of course, be great!, but it's not complexity that is essential to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Append a dynamic stylesheet to the document head:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/707580/2743458)

```js
const today = new Date();
const today_date = today.getDate();

const days = [...Array(today_date).keys()].splice(1).map(
  day => `#day-${day}`
).join(',');

const styles = `
#day-${today_date} {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}

${days} {
  color: silver;
}
`;

var styleSheet = document.createElement("style");
styleSheet.innerText = styles;
document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
```

```html
<div id="day-18" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-19" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-20" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-21" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-22" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-23" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-24" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-25" class="something">content</div>
<div id="day-26" class="something">content</div>
```

Starting by instantiating a [Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp), assigning it to variable `today`, then using it's method [getDate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getDate.asp) to assign the current day number of the month to variable `today_date`.

Next, instantiating an array with that number of elements using [Array object](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/js/javascript-create-array-with-n-elements-example-code/) and providing `today_date` for it's parameter, then get it's key values using it's [keys()](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_keys.asp) method, along with the [spread operator](https://www.w3schools.io/javascript/es6-spread-operator/) and [array literal notation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) to populate the array. `keys()` provides an array of numbers, `0` through yesterday's day number, so [splice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) the array starting from the second element, index `1`, to the end, which results in an array containing day numbers `1` through yesterday.

The [array chain](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-of-array-methods-in-javascript/) is continued by [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)'ing it to [string interpolate](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript.html) the day numbers (keys) into an array of strings containing "#day-" and the day number. Now [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)'ing this array of strings into a single, plain string, then interpolating it into the variable `styles`.

Finally create a stylesheet element using [createElement()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) and append it to the head using [appendChild()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

Comment: Ah! Cool idea. So to change style of previous days would just need a loop of some sort to make all previous days have the new style

Comment: That's perfect! - And I really appreciate the links to the explanations. My goal is to know how it's working and improve. Not just to paste the code. I can already see how to take it apart and use it in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I write some code for you. I think you need this one.

```js
const days = document.getElementById('days');

const date = new Date();
const currentYear = date.getFullYear();
const currentMonth = date.getMonth();
const currentDay = date.getDate();

const currentMonthDaysCount = (year, month) => {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
};

for(let i = 0; i < currentMonthDaysCount(currentYear, currentMonth + 1); i++) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    if(i < currentDay - 1) {
        div.classList.add('pastDays');
    } else if (i == currentDay - 1) {
        div.classList.add('currentDay');
    }
    div.innerHTML = i + 1;
    days.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#days {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#days div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#days div.pastDays {
    background-color: aqua;
}

#days div.currentDay {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="days"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It completely solves the question as I stated it. 
But I now realise how unclear I was! My sincerest apologies.
What I meant was that I would like to create 31 divs separately.
For these 31 divs that I have created separately, I would like to use Javascript to alter their appearance.
I now see that my question makes it look like I wanted the javascript to create the divs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how exactly you are going to use this but I would give you an idea how to achieve this. You can alter my code for you purpose or uses.

```js
function getDaysInCurrentMonth() {
  const date = new Date();
  return new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  ).getDate();
}

var toAdd = document.getElementById("dayContainer");
const totalDays = getDaysInCurrentMonth();
const currentDate = new Date();
const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
let daysClass;

for(var i=1; i < totalDays+1; i++){
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
   newDiv.id = 'day'+i;
   i < currentDay ? daysClass="days pastDay" : ( i == currentDay ? daysClass="days currentDay" : daysClass="days futureDay");
   newDiv.className = daysClass;
   newDiv.innerHTML += i;
   toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```css
.days{padding:5px; margin:5px; width:50px; height:20px;  text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; display:block; position:relative; float:left; }
.pastDay{background:#FFA500; }
.futureDay{background:#0096FF; }
.currentDay{background:#008000; }
.dayContainer{width:100%; display:block; position:relative; float:left; }
```

```html
<div id="dayContainer" class="dayContainer"></div>
```

All the best!

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It completely solves the question as I stated it. 
But I realise now my questions was unclear! My sincerest apologies.
What I meant was that I would like to create 31 divs separately.
For these 31 divs that I have created separately, I would like to use Javascript to alter their appearance.
I can see that my question makes it look like I wanted the javascript to create the divs. But your answer certainly puts me on the right track.