# Cross-browser getClassName JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small project that needs to get all elements by className, there is obviously the HTML5 .getElementsByClassName, but I'm trying to create a little function that provides a small polyfill for it, it's just not working. any help much appreciated. Or if there is an easier way of doing this.

```
function getClassName(element) {
if(!document.getElementsByClassName(element)) {
    var retnode = [];
    var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+element+'\\b');
    var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        var classes = elem[i].className;
        if (myclass.test(classes)) retnode.push(elem[i]);
    }
    return retnode;
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName(element);
}
}
```

Then calling it like so:

```
document.getClassName('active'){
active.className += 'new';
}
```

Comment: The second code example does not make a lot of sense. Is the function not returning the correct elements or is it just not working the way you want to call it?

Comment: Your calling it example makes no sense.

Comment: How would I go about calling it the right way? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Better pollyfill: https://gist.github.com/2299607

Comment: You forgot the `return` in the "else" (which calls the native "getElementsByClassName").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get All Elements in an HTML document with a specific CSS Class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/210377/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling it's not returning anything, no new class names are being added at all.

Comment: @Toddo As stated many times, your second code block makes no sense! So of course it does not add the class name.

Comment: @epascarello How would you suggest the second code block looking?

Comment: Putting brackets with some code in it is not magically going to work. You would have to loop through the set returned by the function. And as stated, you are not even returning anything in the else.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello , using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is wrong.

- The name implies you are getting a class name, not an element.
- You use the variable `element` when you mean className
- check for support is wrong

  - `if(!document.getElementsByClassName) {`
- missing return in else

  - `return document.getElementsByClassName(element);`

I would recommend sse the one from [here](https://gist.github.com/2299607) or [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) to add the polyfill

Grab yourself an addClass method...something like

```
function hasClass(elem,className) {
    return elem.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+className+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(elem,className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem,cls)) elem.className += " "+className;
}
```

Than you will just do

```
var elems = document.getClassName('active');
for (var i=elems.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    addClass(elems[i],"active");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response, really appreciated. Is this something along the lines of what you mean? http://pastebin.com/mFLh0pfq