# How to retrieve data from html page using html class?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="MyName">
  majedur
</div>
```

I want majedur through using MyName

Comment: You should use jquery. :)

Comment: `document.querySelector('.MyName').textContent;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get All Elements in an HTML document with a specific CSS Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210377/get-all-elements-in-an-html-document-with-a-specific-css-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var divText = document.getElementsByClassName('MyName')[0].innerHTML;

alert(divText);//for alert the inner text  of the div

console.log(divText);//write in console the inner text  of the div
```

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementsByClassName("MyName") will return you collection of element that has class "MyName", you can retrieve required by it's index

```
var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("MyName");

if(elements.length > 0){
     var value = elements[0].innerHTML;
}
```